# Assign Call that uses Lambda function on different Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use an assign function to create a new column which has the number of unique values for each column in a seperate df.

I have one df that looks like this

```
df_2

  column_name  value
0     a      2
1     c      3
2     d      4
```

based of another df like so:

```
df_1

      a      b          c
0     apple      apple      1  
1     apple      2      1
2     dinosaur   1      1
```

and I'm trying to use the assign function as so:

```
df_2 = df_2.assign(number_unique = lambda x: (df_1[df_2['column_name']].value_counts()))
```

which doesn't work. I'm sure this is an easy operation to do but can't find a reference anywhere.

Edit:

Expected Output

```
df_2

  column_name  value number_unique 
0     a      2         1
1     b      3         2
2     c      4         1
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can use table markdown for tables: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Comment: ah cheers, could't find a gpod example in the related suggestions

Comment: Please share the expected output of your example, it's not clear from the description.

Comment: could you include your expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your output, you have number unique, but wouldn't this be [2, 3, 1] for [a, b, c]?  In which case: `df_2 = df_2.assign(number_unique = [df_1[q].nunique() for q in df_2['column_name']])` will do this.